# Can I set a general-purpose (not spark.*) parameter when submitting a spark application?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

A normal way to set a parameter in spark-submit is using --conf:

```
spark2-shell --conf "spark.nonexisting=true" --conf "failOnDataLoss=false"
```

Unfortunately this only works for spark.* parameters and I need to set up other parameters which are simply ignored:

```
scala> spark.conf.getAll.filter(p => (p._1 contains "nonexisting") || (p._1 contains "failOnDataLoss"))
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(spark.nonexisting -> true)
```

Of course, I can set anything during run-time, but in my case this is not an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Use general purpose configuration tool like [lightbend/config](https://github.com/lightbend/config).
- Introduce your own namespace in Spark configuration to avoid clashes with built ones, like:

  ```
  --conf "spark.wrodionow.failOnDataLoss=false"
  ```
- For submitted programs, you can also use standard arguments:

  ```
   spark-submit my.jar --some_option ... --other_option ...
  ```

Comment: I can and I do, but this will still not work for any parameter.